# optimizing child/parent structure in one table with a lot of data

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, database-performance

I have a table which has a simple parent child structure

```
products:
- id
- product_id
- time_created
- ... a few other columns
```

It is a parent if product_id IS NULL. Product id behaves here like parent_id. Data inside looks like this:

```
id | product_id 
 1     NULL 
 2      1      
 3      1         
 4     NULL         
 4      4
```

This table is updated every night a new versions are added.

Every user is using a lot of these products but only one version. User is notified if new rows are added for an product_id.

He can stop using id:2 and start using id:3. An another user will continue using id:2 etc.

products table is updated every night and it grows pretty fast. There are around 500000 rows at the moment and every night adds around 20000, probably 5-7000000 changes (new rows) per year.

Is there a way to optimize this database/table structure? Should I change anything? Is it a problem to have so much data in one table?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. why do you need to optimize this?

Comment: 7x10^6 rows/year is not a problem at all if your schema is well defined. Don't ask about a single table try to see the big picture

Comment: @HaleemurAli I am not sure whether I have to optimize this but I want to be ready for the future  and more data.

Comment: @jean thanks. big picture is simple: users, products. i am not experienced working with tables with 7x10^6 rows / year especially if I want to avoid "archiving" some rows because of possible performance loss through too many data in one table

Comment: @tempname, 7*10^6 rows isn't a "lot of data" w.r.t hardware available currently. I'm sure by the time you get to 7*10^7 rows, the hardware that will be available will be able to handle it. Before you spend more time on this problem ask yourself this: will my **rate** of data growth exceed Moore's Law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear.  The sample data is suggesting that the parent-child relationship is only one level deep.  If so, this is not a particularly hard problem.  You can create a query to look up the most recent product id for each product -- and I'm assuming this is the one with the maximum `id`:

```
select id, product_id,
       max(id) over (partition by coalsesce(product_id, id)) as biggest_id
from table t;
```

This is then a lookup table, to get the biggest id.  It would produce:

```
id | product_id | biggest_id
 1     NULL           3
 2      1             3
 3      1             3
 4     NULL           4
 4      4             4
```

If your table has deeper hierarchies, you can solve the problem using recursive CTEs, or by doing the calculation when the table is updated.

Comment: my question is not about relationship but about question: should I split data in multiple tables after having "too many rows" (i.e. > 10 milions)?

Comment: @tempname . . . Your question is not clear.  Before splitting the tables, you should strive to add the best indexes and table partitions.  Sometimes splitting tables is necessary.  10 million is not that many rows.